# How to sum values of a column where the column name has been duplicated?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'grps': list('aaabbcaabcccbbc'), 
                'vals': [12,345,-3,1,45,14,4,52,54,23,235,-21,57,-3,87]})
```

I want to find the sum of 'vals' of each group: a,b,c

I've tried using the .sum() function but I'm struggling on how to group all the values of the same letter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**`GroupBy.sum`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html) :

```
out= df.groupby("grps", as_index=False).sum()
```

##### # Output :

```
print(out)

  grps  vals
0    a   410
1    b   154
2    c   338
```